# SQLite: get day

Tags: database, sqlite, select

How can I return the day of a DateTime in SQLite?

I have my field Date stored as a DateTime.
Now I would like get the day from each row (just the day, not the full date).

I tried using the following, but it doesn't work.
It doesn't give an error, but it just returns nothing

```
SELECT strftime('%d', Date) FROM sessiondate
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT strftime('%d', `Date`) FROM sessiondate
```

might work

Comment: Perhaps check the format of your Date field - according to the docs, if you try a date function on an invalid format, it will return Null. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: Shouldn't the field know which format to use, since it's a Datetime?

Comment: When you DESCRIBE the table, what kind of column does it say the Date field is?

Comment: When i select all from the master I can see it is a DateTime (this is how i created the column). I can't use describe command because SQLite doesn't support that

Comment: Like trickwallet said check the format of the 'sessiondate' columns. sqllite is very forgiving when inserting data and will store anything its given as a string even if its invalid.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT strftime('%d', `Date`) FROM sessiondate GROUP BY strftime('%d', `Date`);
```

This will get each Day in your db, you can build on it by adding to Select, Where conditions or ORDER BY clause.